# GAN training: Why not wait for the G or D to catch up?

Tags: machine-learning, gan

It is known, that GANs are hard to train.

> ... and it proved to be very easy that one of the two overpowers the other early in the training process
> (Quote from [here](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/stylegan-a-step-by-step-introduction.md))

I was wondering, why this isn't solved by waiting for the worse player to catch up, before the gradient becomes unusable?

This could be simply implemented by thresholding the discriminators accuracy, i.e to just improve the generator when discriminator is correct in 60% of the cases, and to solely improve the discriminator when accuracy drops below 40%?

All other workarounds seem rather complicated to me, so I am interested in your opinions!